# Adding a line to the middle of a file with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an ansible playbook entry which looks for a php array

```
$array = {
  'some\value',
};
```

And adds a line to that array

```
$array = {
  'some\value',
  'another\value,
};
```

This is what I tried, and while it adds the line I'm after, it also keeps adding it every pass

```
- name: Add another\value dummy.php
  lineinfile:
    dest=/path/to/dummy.php
    insertafter='some\value'
    line="  'another\value',"
```

If I keep running the playbook, I'll get

```
$array = {
  'some\value',
  'another\value,
  'another\value,
  'another\value,
  'another\value,
  'another\value,
  'another\value,
};
```

I realise I'm probably doing something really stupid here, but I can't see how to say `"unless_it_exists='another\value'"`

I also tried this, which doesn't work

```
- name: Add another\value dummy.php
  lineinfile:
    dest=/path/to/dummy.php
    regexp="'some\\value',\n}"
    backrefs=yes
    line="'some\\value'\n  'another\\value',\n}"
```

**Edited 2014-07-28**

Just to clarify - the file I'm editing is [**this one** https://github.com/...](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7e4107d453222bea687b8932a3b61d9b4bb410dd/app/config/app.php) and I'm trying to add an array member at line 124, like this:

```
        'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',
```

Comment: You probably need to change your regex logic to match for your "_(some value)_ `AND NOT` _(some value `AND` another value)_"

Comment: @Mxx I think the issue really is the new line characters - regex typically only works on a single line, unless you can convince it otherwise...

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using? I can't seem to reproduce the problem on 1.6.10 on OSX.

Comment: @RamondelaFuente Ansible 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce the behaviour you describe, because the whole point of the lineinfile module is to have that "unless_it_exists" functionality. The only thing I can think of is something is changing line after Ansible - for example your IDE is replacing spaces with tabs.

I did come up with the following task:
(dummy.php now contains the gist contents)

```
- name: Add GeneratorsServiceProvider to dummy.php
  lineinfile:
    dest=files/dummy.php
    insertafter="^        'Illuminate\\\\Workbench\\\\WorkbenchServiceProvider',"
    line="        'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider',"
```

I believe this does what you want.

*I've changed `insertafter` because it is a regular expression, and backslashes should be escaped. This becomes quite ugly with four backslashes to account for Python also parsing the '\' character, but I havent figured out how to use the [raw string notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) within Ansible.*

Comment: In the end, I adjusted your solution a little, in the insertafter, I changed the spaces between ^ and ' to ^\s*' and, changed line (after reading [this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4818)) to line="{{'\t'}}{{'\t'}}'Way\\Generators\\GeneratorsServiceProvider'," but that's because I messed up my spacing in the original question. Very *very* many thanks to you!